My HTML and CSS gets ignored in my .NET code
I am trying to create an invoice look-alike PDF document with pure HTML and CSS code in my ASP.NET MVC web app, but whenever I try to create the PDF file, it gets created but it's just a blank page, nothing on it...
I am using HTML Renderer as a library to help me print out the PDF document.
This is my code:
  private async Task<IActionResult> GenerateInvoice(IEnumerable<InvoiceDTO> modelData)
        {
            try
            {
                var document = new PdfDocument();
                var DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
 string HtmlContent = $@"
     <html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{{
                padding: 50px;
                display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    background-color: antiquewhite;
                }}
        #topContainer{{
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    align-items: center;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    background-color: aquamarine;
                }}
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=""topContainer"">
    <p>Date: {DateTimeNow} </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>";


            PdfGenerator.AddPdfPages(document, HtmlContent, PageSize.A4);
            byte[] response;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                document.Save(ms);
                response = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return File(new MemoryStream(response), "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

I have more classes and more code and I have tried it in a .html file and it all worked (of course I had to replace the double quotes and brackets with single ones).
Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Does your code work in a console app, creating a non-empty PDF?

Well yes, I can perform every other operation in my app, such as Login, Logout, CRUD, etc etc. I also have a similar method to print another pdf document with a datatable and there is no such problem. Only with this code it creates an empty pdf file.

What's the point of saving the PDF in a MemoryStream, then get the byte[] from the MemoryStream, then creating a second MemoryStream from the byte[]?
If it works in a local console, but not on the server, then the issue could be related to font problems. The process on the server may not have access to the Windows Fonts folder or maybe other restrictions apply. Or something completely different.

Since you didn't mention which package you are using in your code, so that I just searched about PdfGenerator.AddPdfPages and I found this reply which using Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core and it  worked well in my side. If I swtiched to your html content, I will get exception like below.

Per my test, I found if I removed display: flex; in the style definition, it will work. In the mean time, I also reproduced your issue which generating a pdf file with no content(remove styles defined for body and only keeps styles defined for the div), and I noticed when it's null, the file size would be  1kb, but if it contains content, it will be 18kb. Any way, I think this issue is due to the style we used.

Here's my codes, and I installed package <PackageReference Include="Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core" Version="1.0.0" />:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PdfSharpCore;
using PdfSharpCore.Pdf;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;

namespace WebAppMvc.Controllers
{
    public class PdfController : Controller    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var document = new PdfDocument();
            var DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
            string HtmlContent = $@"
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <style>
                            body{{
                                padding: 50px;
                                justify-content: center;
                                align-items: center;
                                flex-direction: column;
                                background-color: antiquewhite;
                            }}
                            #topContainer{{
                                    height: 100px;
                                    width: 100%;
                                    justify-content: space-between;
                                    align-items: center;
                                    flex-direction: row;
                                    background-color: aquamarine;
                                }}
                         </style>
                    </head>
                    <body >
                        <div id=""topContainer"" >
                        <p>Date: {DateTimeNow} </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>";


            PdfGenerator.AddPdfPages(document, HtmlContent, PageSize.A4);
            Byte[] res = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                document.Save(ms);
                res = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return File(new MemoryStream(res), "application/pdf", "test1.pdf");

        }
    }
}


This is because you put the html codes inside the action method. You must create a corresponding view for each action and move the html codes there.

Hi @esmail , I know but the thing is that I use this html and css codes for a PDF document, not for a View component. So I need it in an action method. I have to mention that I even pass some data in that code as well.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
